# This code works perfect on armv7 (32 bit) but not on arm64 (64 bit)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, arm64

**The code:**

```
UIColor * color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.colorData];

if ([countedColorSet containsObject:color]) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

**What's wrong:**

No errors, but "Do stuff" never runs (64 bit)... even when 'color' is identical to one stored in the set. Testing with no other conditions changed on 32 bit works fine and "Do stuff" runs.

**So:**

Am I going crazy? What could I be missing?

Comment: Are you only archived the data under 32bit environment?

Comment: @kukushi nope, reinstalled app in the simulator to make sure. The code for archiving is: event.colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];

Comment: More details are needed. Have you do some other stuff on the data, like writing/reading? And what you mean by 'identical', are they the exact same object (same address) or just the same color type?

Comment: @kukushi on closer inspection, I've found that archiving and unarchiving a UIColor object changes the color's rgb values very slightly - only noticeable on arm64 when CGFloat has greater accuracy. Not sure why this is, and I'm not sure if there's a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed via an Apple Technical support incident that this is a bug relating to the archiving class on arm64. Their suggestion was to build a custom archiver class instead.